# Cannot randomly assign **per day in data set** individuals to 3 groups according to required percentages - 10%/45%/45%

Tags: python, pandas, random, sample, sampling

I want to randomly assign individuals from an existing dataset into 3 different group according to a fixed **daily percentage**. Below, is the sample dataset:

```
 Date               Customer_ID
 1. 1/3/2019         411
 2. 1/3/2019         414
 3. 1/3/2019         421
 4. 5/3/2019         431
 5. 5/3/2019         433
 6. 5/3/2019         441
 7. 6/3/2019         442
 8. 6/3/2019         443
 9. 6/3/2019         444
```

I used the Python code below to create the groups. While the overall traffic % is correct, the groups are not correctly assigned according to the required percentage **per day**.

```
Group   %
 A    10%
 B    45%
 C    45%

              Expected outcome               Actual outcome
 Date      Group A  Group B Group C     Group A Group B Group C
  1/3/2019  10%      45%    45%           7%    2%       91%
  1/4/2019  10%      45%    45%           12%   25%      63%
  1/5/2019  10%      45%    45%           15%   50%      35%
  1/6/2019  10%      45%    45%           20%   61%      19%
  1/7/2019  10%      45%    45%           2%    7%       91%
  1/8/2019  10%      45%    45%           1%    12%      87%
  1/9/2019  10%      45%    45%           9%    21%      70%
  1/10/2019 10%      45%    45%           13%   25%      62%
  Overall   10%      45%    45%           10%   45%      45%
```

Current code:

```
# Create 3 different groups that have traffic assigned 10%/45%/45%
df['Groups'] = df.groupby('Date')['Customer_ID']\
.transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(['Group_A', 'Group_B', 'Group_C'],
                                      len(x),  p= [0.1,0.45,0.45]))
```

The code only gives desired output on the overall dataset but not **per day** (as shown in the actual outcome table)

Which python code can I use to create the three groups according to the required distribution **per day**?

Comment: Just to be sure - provide some code how you generate "Actual outcome" part?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems that I misunderstood the question at the beginning (long day). IMHO, your code works as expected (sorry, I just generated numbers instead of dates):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rows = 10000
dates = np.random.choice(range(10), size = rows)
Customer_IDs = np.random.choice(range(2*rows), size = rows, replace = False)
data = np.vstack([dates, Customer_IDs]).T

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date", "Customer_ID"])

df['Groups'] = df.groupby('Date')['Customer_ID']\
    .transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(['Group_A', 'Group_B', 'Group_C'],
                                      len(x),  p= [0.1,0.45,0.45]))

print(df.groupby(['Date','Groups']).agg({'Date':'count'})\
    .groupby(level = 0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum())) )
```

Now, there might be some randomness and strictly 10/45/45 is very unlikely.

What I would suggest is to check manually what distribution you have per some specific date and compare to the "actual" table:

```
from collections import Counter
test_date = 1 # change this to '1/3/2019' for example
cntr = Counter(df[df["Date"]==test_date]["Groups"])
cntr_sum = sum(cntr.values())
print( {k: np.round(100 * v/cntr_sum, 2)
            for k,v in cntr.items()} )
```

PS. Hopefully, you will have something like that:

```
{'Group_B': 43.35, 'Group_C': 46.23, 'Group_A': 10.42}
```

Hope this time I got it right!

Comment: Yes, thanks @Alexander B. strictly 10/45/45 is very unlikely.

Comment: @NicolaM, if this answers your question - don't forget to mark it as a correct answer!